# What is the meaning of 'Friend the Member for'?

Tags: british-english

I found that they in the British Parliament use the term 'Friend the Member for...' as shown in the link below when, maybe, referring to a member of parliament. And I just have no idea what the exact meaning is and how this expression can be explained grammatically.

Is this a kind of apposition expression like 'Richard the Lion Heart'?

https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2022-02-23/debates/CB7C95D5-704B-441D-B8C6-3CF7B2A08B22/ChildSexualExploitationByOrganisedNetworks

Answer (score 2):

They are not using the term "Friend the Member." They are using two different terms, and you have mashed together the middle parts!

The terms are:

- An honorific: *my hon. [honourable] Friend*
- A job title: *the Member for [*constituency*]*

"My honourable Friend" is a term used to refer to someone in the speaker's own political party (according to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/my_honourable_friend)). "The Member for [*e.g.*] Rotherham" is the official title for a Member of Parliament (of any party), and it describes exactly which constituency they represent.

"Member of Parliament" is capitalized properly—capital M, capital P. I am not sure why "Friend" is capitalized; it may be for a historical reason or it may be because the transcript abbreviates "honourable" as "hon." and automatically capitalizes the next letter after the full stop.

---

In the US Senate and House of Representatives you can hear a similar form of speech; people will refer to other members as "my friend the Senator from Arizona" or "the gentlewoman from Rhode Island." Here he "honourable" has been dropped.

Answer (score 1):

It is customary in the British Parliament for one member to refer to another member as "my friend". Then the specific person meant id identified not by name, but by the place that member represents.

Thus when a members says:

> my hon. Friend the Member for Redditch

The reference is to (Rachel Maclean) and when the member says:

> my hon. Friend the Member for Corby

the reference is to Tom Pursglove. Individual names are traditionally omitted to avoid the appearance of commenting on a person, and "my friend" is used to avoid the appearance of hostility.

Similarly in British courts it is traditional for a barrister to refer to the opposing barrister as "my  learned friend".